# Como funciona a captura de dados de um formulário?

Tags: java, java-ee

Tenho esse código para pegar dados de um formulário:

```
@WebServlet(name = "computador", urlPatterns = {"/computador"})
public class computador extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        float total = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("total"));
        float preco = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("preco"));
        float consumo = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("consumo"));
    }

}
```

Mas não sei por que ele utiliza o `request` pra pegar os dados, ao invés do `response`. E para que serve o `response`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Request é para enviar pedidos ao servidor.
>
> Response é a resposta do servidor para o cliente.

Uma aplicação ou sistema web funciona totalmente diferente de uma desktop ou console onde todo o processamento acontence na máquina local.

Uma aplicação web deve obedecer o ciclo do protocolo http, que funciona em dois tempos: pedido e a resposta.

O termo **request** significa que o cliente(um navegador por exemplo) está fazendo uma solicitação ao servidor de algum recurso, seja ele uma página html, imagem, download etc o servidor recebe e processa o pedido e devolve algo pode ser html, json etc esse retorno recebe o nome de **response**.

Comment: E quando eu vou utilizar o response.algumaCoisa?

Comment: Quando você desejar enviar algo para o cliente, como resposta a uma requisição.